# Create a plane perpendicular to the long diagonal of a cube

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mathematics

How can I create a plane perpendicular to the long diagonal of a cube? I have this which isn't correct.

[image: pic]

Animation of plane perpendicular to the long diagonal of a cube (**it should look like this**).
[image: Animation plane perpendicular to the long diagonal off a cube]

Animation with audio of why.
https://youtu.be/fWsmq9E4YC0?t=118

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a face-type Custom Orientation from any 3 points:

1. Edit Mode: Select the 3 points you want the plane to be aligned to and create a [Custom Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations) from them.. ensure it's being used.
2. Object Mode: Select the plane, and Object > Transform > 'Align to Orientation'.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you have to use differents points for the orientation.

Comment: Robin? Does that give the good solution?

Comment: @lemon ... ahhh...  Hope that's better, if that's what you mean....

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Robin, yes. Many wrong upvoted answers here... but now that's ok

Comment: Glad to see the best answer poping first :)

Answer (score 10):

To rotate the plane so that it is exactly perpendicular to the long diagonal of the cube, one can use either a constraint or a little bit of trigonometry.

### Constraint

With the plane centered on one of the corners,
[image: 1]

Add a *Track To* constraint and set the target to the cube.
[image: 2]

---

### Trigonometry

Alternatively, one can use a short python expression to find the correct rotation.

First, rotate the plane around either the X or Y axis using the expression `atan(2 / sqrt(2)) * 360 / tau`.
[image: 3]

Then, rotate the plane 45° around the Z axis.

Comment: OMG ....are u math professor or why is this "a little bit of trigonometry"? +1 for "a little bit" ;)

Comment: Two good solutions and the only ones to be exact here!

Comment: only ones until Robin updates his answer...  ;)

Comment: @Chris Nope, not a professor. I hate math class XD

Answer (score 3):

use math, cube is rotated to xyz axis correctly, create plane that is rotated correctly as well by default.
Now, rotate it by 45 degrees on Y axis (or X), rotate it again on Z axis by 45 degree...

You end up with this and it is in right position. Set your orientation to Normal:
[image]

Now when you move with G+Z it will go this way

[image]
[image]

Now you just need to animate it on this movement and make it boolean cutter

Comment: +1 sounds for me like the easiest solution...

Comment: 45 and 45 does not work

Comment: did you rotate it in right order?

Comment: @MikoCG, yes. Have a look at HISEROD answer where the good angles are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the plane 45deg on both X & Y axis, then snap to the vertex of the cube.

Comment: 45 and 45 does not work...